# How to check which value was used for WorkflowHostUri with Register-SPWorkflowService?

Tags: 2013, powershell, workflow-manager

I have a production environment with three Workflow Manager 1.0 servers in a farm.  We also have a virtual URL that is used by NLB to spread the load between these servers. Register-SPWorkflowService PowerShell command was possibly used with a wrong -WorkflowHostUri value that looks on one of the three servers instead of a virtual NLB URL. The question is, how do I check it? Neither of the following commands helped me to answer this question:

```
Get-WFFarm
Get-WFFarmstatus
Get-WFScope
```

This is, for instance, what Get-WFFarm returns:

[image]

I also tried looking [into scopes](https://lennytech.wordpress.com/category/sharepoint-2013/workflow-manager/) and could not find any mention of WF URLs used.

I would like to run Register-SPWorkflowService again, but I can't do it because It's a production environment and I need to make sure if a human error really exists before changing anything.

So, does anyone know a PowerShell command or any other way of telling what URL is used for the Workflow Manager Farm by SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following cmdlets:

```
$site = (Get-SPWebapplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | ?{$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication}).Sites[0]

$wfmProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "Workflow Service Application Proxy"}
$wfmProxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress($site)
```

Comment: Thank you, Trevor! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can get proxy by this command $wfmProxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy